# Redirect user to another page once increment value reach 100

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a UI where when service return true value, I have created a loading bar which will reach 100%, after reaching 100% user should be redirect to another page.

lets assume, If the service return false value, the status bar stay at 10% loaded.

[Link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/veer_vin/4t6bppjs/)

I have created function were I have written the progress bar logic and I am returning true value when service return true and redirecting to other URL.

everything is working great. But I want the progress bar to reach 100% and after that only user should be redirected. Below is the code (And above is jsfiddle link):

```
var serviceStatus = true; // Suppose value from service
var elem = document.getElementById("blueBar"); 
var perNum = document.getElementById("progressPercentage");

var width = 10; // intial progress bar width
var id = setInterval(progressBar, 10);
function progressBar() {
    if (width >= 100 || serviceStatus === false) {
        clearInterval(id);
        return false;
    } else {
        width ++;
        elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
        perNum.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
        //return true;
    }
}

function redirectUser(progressBar) {
    console.log(progressBar);
    // if (frame === true) {
    //  window.location = "http://www.google.com";
    // };
}

redirectUser(progressBar());
```

Thanks, any questions? please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/4t6bppjs/10/

```
function redirectUser(progressBar) {
    if(progressBar) {
        setTimeout( function() {
            //---- window.location
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

I just added setTimeout.

Comment: Nice that works great, but using of setTimeout function compulsory? just a though, any other way?

Comment: @Veer give some time to think, will definitely get back to you with some other solution.

Comment: I have update the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/shiladitya/4t6bppjs/11/ . I have commented the window.location. try using it and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Check that when the width reaches 100 % then only redirect to other page. So add condition in your `progressBar function` like this. Have added timeout just to show that the width reaches 100% and then it is redirected. Even if you don't use timeout that will redirect.

```
function progressBar() {
        if (width >= 100 || serviceStatus === false) {
            clearInterval(id);
            return false;
        } else {
            width ++;
            elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
            perNum.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
            return true;
        }
    }

function redirectUser(progressBar) {
    if(progressBar){
      setTimeout(function(){
         window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
      },1000)
  }
```

This may not work on fiddle or Stackoverflow Snippets because `'X-Frame-Options'` is set to `'SAMEORIGIN'` in frames used to display results.

Comment: yes we can add that condition if(width=100) and then redirect user, What if I want to use return true and false and pass that as parameter in another function?

Answer (score 0):

Your methods seems correct, but you are calling them incorrectly.

```
redirectUser(progressBar());
```

This will call `redirectUser` first and then `progressBar()` that's why you are seeing undefined. If you have to pass function or callback to another function you are not suppose to call it.

You can pass it like another variables.

```
redirectUser(progressBar);
```

Hope this will help you.

```
var blueProgressBar = {
    initialize: function() {
        var serviceStatus = true; // Suppose value from service
        var elem = document.getElementById("blueBar"); 
        var perNum = document.getElementById("progressPercentage");

        var width = 10; // intial progress bar width
        var id = setInterval(progressBar, 10);

        function progressBar() {
            if (width >= 100 || serviceStatus === false) {
                clearInterval(id);
                redirectUser()
            } else {
                width ++;
                elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
                perNum.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
            }
        }

        function redirectUser() {
          console.log("redirect");
          window.location = "http://www.google.com";
        }

        progressBar();
    }

}

$(function() {
    blueProgressBar.initialize();
});
```

Comment: I was passing a function as a parameter to another function. progressBar() was returning either false or true value. false when from service url we get false output and vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var blueProgressBar = {

 initialize: function() {
  var serviceStatus = true; // Suppose value from service
  var elem = document.getElementById("blueBar"); 
  var perNum = document.getElementById("progressPercentage");

  var width = 10; // intial progress bar width
  var id = setInterval(progressBar, 10);
  function progressBar() {
   if (width >= 100 || serviceStatus === false) {
    clearInterval(id);
    return false;
   } else {
    width ++;
    elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
    perNum.innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
    //return true;
   }
   if(width >= 100 && serviceStatus){
    window.location = "redirect url";
   }
  }

  function redirectUser(progressBar) {
   console.log(progressBar);
   
  }

  redirectUser();
 }

}

$(function() {
 blueProgressBar.initialize();
});
```

```css
.upgrade-service-level-bar {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 20px 40px 20px 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

.bar-full-witdh {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
}

#blueBar {
    width: 10%;
    height: 6px;
    background-color: #007cba;
    display: block;
}

.bar-full-witdh span:last-child {
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    right: -30px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="upgrade-service-level-bar">
 <div class="bar-full-witdh">
  <span id="blueBar"></span>
  <span id="progressPercentage">10%</span>
 </div>
</div>
<br>
<p>
Once progress bar reaches 100% the redirect should happen.
</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: var serviceStatus = true; change this value to false and see if your code works.

I have created that variable to just show that service can return either true or false value. On which we want to show if we have to redirect user or not.

When the progress bar is at 100% then only user should redirect to other page.

When the progress bar will be 100%? when the service return true value.

Comment: it is not necessary to redirect user to another page if serviceStatus is false